# Induction motor simple power and torque

Tags: induction-motor

The output power is 100hp and slip is 0.02 and efficiency of 90%,4 pole induction motor

Want to find the shaft torque(output torque).

So I guess to find the torque we use the equation

P(out) = T(out)/w , but **i'm not sure w is same with input(?) w.**

here is my tried solution

```
Td = p(out)/w
S= ns(1-s) , 0.02 /(1-0.02) = ns = 0.0204
And find the n
S= ns-n/ns , n= 0.01992
Pg = Tw, 
T(out)= 74.6kw/[(2pi/60)n]= 35761
```

can i use the same w for output power torque? and why? 
Also, please check the solution.

Comment: You have a number of errors here due to using the wrong numbers in the wrong places. Try writing down the units of each and every quantity you are using, i.e. watts, newton-metres, RPM. (Hint: Torque is power divided by **angular frequency**.)

Comment: You also appear to be confusing angular velocity, \$\omega\$ (measured in radians/sec) with input power (\$P_{input}\$ measured in watts, W.)

Answer (score 3):

Torque is given by:

$$
\tau = \frac{P_{shaft}}{\omega}
$$

Where \$P_{shaft}\$ is the output power of the motor (shaft power) and \$\omega\$ is the angular frequency of rotation.

The power supply in my country is 50 Hz, so a 4-pole motor has a synchronous (zero slip) speed of 1,500 RPM. Converting to angular frequency (radians per second), we get

$$ 1,500\ RPM \times \frac{2\pi\  rad.s^{-1}}{60\ RPM} = 157.1\ rad.s^{-1} $$

Slip is 2%, so the motor is running at 98% of synchronous speed :

$$
\omega = 157.1\ rad.s^{-1} \times 0.98 = 153.9\ rad.s^{-1}
$$

The output power of your motor is 100 HP. In metric units that is

$$
P_{shaft} = 100\ HP \times \frac{746\ W}{1\ HP} = 74,600\ W
$$

Giving

$$
\tau = \frac{74,600\ W}{153.9\ rad.s^{-1}} = 484.6\ N.m
$$

Note I have written down the units of every figure I have used. This makes it much easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: When you find the Developed torque, Used the original w=157.1?

Comment: @sayuri: I'm not going to do your homework for you. I suggest looking up the "power flow diagram" for an induction motor. Mulukutla S. Sarma's *Electric Machines* (WM. C. Brown Publishers, 1985) talks about this in section §7.4 on *Polyphase Induction Machine Performance*.

Answer (score 0):

So the key information:

Power = 100HP = 74,570W
Slip = 2%
Efficiency = 90%
Pole = 4

mains freq = 60 (determined from OP initial calc).
sync speed = 1800rpm   (main_freq/(pole/2))*60

Key equations:

P=T \$\omega\$                  P=Power, T= Torque, \$\omega\$ = rotor speed 
s = (fs - fr)/fs  (s=slip, fs = slip speed, fr = sync speed)

so the slip speed = 1764rpm.

\$ Via P = T\omega =>  T = P/\omega =>  T = 74570/((1764/60)*2*pi) => T = 403Nm \$

Comment: Naib: you may want to look up [this guide on how to use math markup in answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so instead of writing `P=Tw` you can write \$P=\tau\times\omega\$.

Comment: Naib: Remember that the dollar signs need backslashes - `\$ ... \$`, not `$ ... $`. As in `\$ x^2 + y^2 = z^2\$`.

Comment: thanks, the issue is it is not being rendered in chrome (neither is your post below specific for 50Hz) ...